# Слетели стили в WordPress

Tags: wordpress

Ребят, может кто поможет... Я новичок в этом деле, объясните в чем здесь ошибка, почему не прогружает стили админки? Как мне показалось, после смены ip адреса между виртуалкой и ос все накрылось.Сеть локальная.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите html код загрузки стилей

Comment: Сайт перенесен неправильно. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82-%d0%bd%d0%b0-wordpress